# Cakephp 3 unable to save multiple translations at same time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to save multiple translations for column name in a single form submit but it always result in an exception 'name' doesn't have a default value. Below given is my implementation according to cakephp's latest documentation.

**Table Structure for words**

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table word_i18n structure that hold all the translations for table words**

```
CREATE TABLE `word_i18n` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `locale` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
 `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `foreign_key` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `content` mediumtext,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `locale` (`locale`),
 KEY `model` (`model`),
 KEY `row_id` (`foreign_key`),
 KEY `field` (`field`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Added the translation behavior to the WordsTable**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('words');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->addBehavior('Translate', [
        'fields' => ['name'],
        'translationTable' => 'word_i18n',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Validation Rules
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('name');
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('slug')
        ->add('slug', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider'=> 'table']);
   return $validator;
}
```

**Word Entity with Translation Trait**

```
class Word extends Entity
{
    use TranslateTrait;

     /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ];
}
```

**Controller Method to render and handle the submission**

```
public function add()
{
     I18n::locale("en"); // Sets the default locale
    $word = $this->Words->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $word = $this->Words->patchEntity($word, $this->request->data, ['translations' => true]);
        //debug($word);die;
        if ($this->Words->save($word)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The word has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The word could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('word'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['word']);
}
```

**And at last the form to submit data**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($word); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Word') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('_translations.en.name',['class'=>"form-control ui-flat", "label" => __("Name [{0}]", ["English"])]);
            echo $this->Form->input('_translations.ja.name',['class'=>"form-control ui-flat", "label" => __("Name [{0}]", ["Japanese"]) ]);
            echo $this->Form->input('_translations.ko.name',['class'=>"form-control ui-flat", "label" => __("Name [{0}]", ["Korean"])]);
            echo $this->Form->input('_translations.zh.name',['class'=>"form-control ui-flat", "label" => __("Name [{0}]", ["Chinese"])]);
            echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),array('class'=>"btn btn-success ui-flat pull-right"));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Everything is implement to the cakephp's documentation but always got an validation error for fields **name** is **_required This field is required** 
And if remove the _translations.en from the name first form field and submits it passes the validation but leads to an sql error **Field 'name' doesn't have a default value**.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to remember to add _translations into the **$_accessible fields** of your entity as well.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html

Answer (score 0):

To save the multiple translations at same time just make sure translated columns does not exists in the table.

Here we have to remove the **name** from the table **words**.
And also remove the validation rule **requirePresense** for the translated column.